# How to properly call a function from a different file?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this code here in my main file.

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'load_functions.php');

add_shortcode( 'ccss-show-recipes', 'ccss_show_tag_recipes' );
function ccss_show_tag_recipes() {

global $post;
global $wp;

$html = '';

$url = home_url( $wp->request );
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$currentPage = end($pathFragments);
// $html.= '<p>'.$currentPage.'</p>';

    if ($currentPage == 'recipes') {

      ccss_load_all_recipes();


    } elseif ( in_array( $currentPage ,["cleanse","combine","commence","commit","complete","consolidate"] ) ) {

        //load_phases();

    } elseif ( in_array( $currentPage ,["basic-marinades","basic-stock-recipes"] ) ) {

       // load_recipe_type();

    }

    return $html;

   // Restore original post data.
   wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

and I have function here in load_functions.php

```
function ccss_load_all_recipes() {
 //code here that wont return

$html .= '<p>test</p>'; //--> It wont display this
echo 'test'; //---> This will be displayed
}
```

The problem when I call  **ccss_load_all_recipes()** it won't return anything, any ideas on what error I made? But when I try an echo statement it returns it

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function `css_load_all_recipes()` does not know the variable `$html`. In order to achieve that you should pass the $html variable into the function and return it again at the end.

```
// in your main file
$html = ccss_load_all_recipes($html);

// in load_functions.php
function ccss_load_all_recipes($html = '') {
    $html .= '<p>test</p>';
    return $html;
}
```

Edit: other possibilities are: declaring `$html` as a global variable, or passing `$html` as reference so you don't have to return the altered html back to the main file. But I would advise against both of these options, unless you run into the exact same problem many times within your application.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! It works! I didnt know that you still have to pass a the variable! But thank you! I will mark this as correct!